# regular expression for allowing number and null value but not just whitespace like " "

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

i need a regular expression for checking numbers , allowing 'null' value and not allowing whitespasces;

in CustomerViewModel:

```
[Display(Name = "Phone")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{4,15}", ErrorMessage = "{0} is not correct!")]
public string CustomerPhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

it allows numbers and 'null' value and "             ".
in editing mode of form, when my textbox has "                 " ,it does not show error!
i want to show error for "            "  and stop posting form.
how can i do that?

Comment: Why don't you consider isnullorempty() ???.Though it is not regex you can use it to achieve desired result in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for allowing only numbers without spaces

```
^(\s*|\d+)$
```

Comment: it allows me that i type whitespace in my text editor and post it!

Comment: @mortazavi I tested it [here](http://rubular.com/), you can also check on online tools

Answer (score 0):

for allowing numerical and "null" value.*provided null is in lower-case and null is a word.

```
([0-9a-z]+)
```

for allowing only numerical

```
([0-9]+)
```

Comment: it allows me that i type whitespace in my text editor and post it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
@"^[0-9][0-9 ]{4,15}$"
```

Comment: it allows me that i type whitespace in my text editor and post it!

Comment: @"^[0-9][0-9 ]{4,15}$" try this

Comment: i saw that, in my client it doesn't show regular expression error, but when it goes to my action and checks (ModelStat.Isvalid), it throws regular expression error and return false.

Comment: @mortazavi why don't you put this regex in cshtml page?