# .Net Core MVC Validate Optional Phone Number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't want the phone number to be required. But, if it's not null, I want it to be validated.

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public string? Phone { get; set; }
```

I know how to validate it if it's required. I don't know how to validate it when it's optional.

Comment: Did you try **regular expression**? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629575/regular-expression-for-allowing-number-and-null-value-but-not-just-whitespace-li

Comment: @Soheil yes I did.  Same outcome.  If the field is [string?] it doesn't get validated, if it's [string] it's validated and required.

Comment: @Soheil...[RegularExpression(@"^$|^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid phone number.")] did the trick.  Added ^$| at the beginning and that did the trick.  many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PhoneAttribute apparently doesn't allow an optional phone number. Create your own attribute; https://stackoverflow.com/a/62436642